# How to use KeyHolder in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I tried to save data to an H2 database using Spring Boot JdbcTamplate by the following code:

schema.sql :

```
create table if not exists Taco (
    id identity,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    createdAt timestamp not null
);
```

that is my repository class:

```
public class JdbcTacoRepository {
    public long saveTacoInfo(Taco taco) {
        taco.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        PreparedStatementCreator psc = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(
                "insert into Taco (name, createdAt) values ( ?,? )"
                , Types.VARCHAR, Types.TIMESTAMP
        ).newPreparedStatementCreator(Arrays.asList(
                taco.getName()
                , new Timestamp(taco.getCreatedAt().getTime())
        ));

        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbc.update(psc, keyHolder);

        return Objects.requireNonNull(
            keyHolder.getKey()         // in this place keyHolder.getKey() is null
        ).longValue();
    }
}
```

but after calling `jdbc.update(psc, keyholder);`I get `keyHolder` is `Null` reference object.

What did I wrong? 
Please help me.

Comment: is it `keyholder` that you get null or is it `keyHolder.getKey()`?

Comment: @Ankur the ```keyHolder.getKey()``` is null in my case.

Comment: @buræquete thanks for the help! Your advice to add ```preparedStatementCreatorFactory.setReturnGeneratedKeys(true);``` is working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
preparedStatementCreatorFactory.setReturnGeneratedKeys(true);
```

before you create a `PreparedStatementCreator` with `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory`. Then the created `psc` should return the generated key which then can be picked up by `KeyHolder`.